# Testing multiple outputs with MRUnit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers, mrunit

Is there a way to test a reduce class with `MRUnit` that uses `MultipleOutputFormat` to write to multiple output files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like support for `MultipleOutputs` is still work in progress in [the MRUnit Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-13).

That being said, I found someone who implemented his own drivers subclassing MRUnit's `MapReduceDriver` to make it work with `MultipleOutputs` [here](https://gist.github.com/1717820), hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for finding chetan's drivers on GitHub. Have you had a chance to use them yourself by any chance? It is unclear to me how it accounts for the namedOutput and baseOutputPath parameters of MultipleOutputs.write().

Comment: Unfortunately the linked code doesn't work, it's not even valid Java code. MultiOutputMapReduceDriver.java:37 wants to use symbol "configuration", which is undefined. Also, in MultiOutputReduceDriver.java:34, the constructor used for class MockReduceContextWrapper is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

MRUnit 1.1.0 has been released in June 2014 (see http://mrunit.apache.org/)

This latest release includes support for `MultipleOutputs` (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-13)